# Hook to Use Second Field Before Fallback

Tags: hooks, advanced-custom-fields

I'll provide background below, but the TLDR is that I can't find the right field/function to insert the post title at the <need_something_here> in the code below.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'before_fallback_tagline_text' ) ) {
    /**
     * Add description meta tag with excerpt text.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function before_fallback_tagline_text( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

      // Check for banner image setting
       if ( empty( $value ) && 'tagline' === $field['name'] ) {

          // Retrieve thumbnail setting (As attachment ID)
          $fallback = get_post_meta( $post_id,<need_something_here>, true );

          // Substitute the fallback for the missing mobile attachment
          if ( ! empty( $fallback ) )
             $value = $fallback;
       }
       return $value;
    }
}
add_filter( 'acf/load_value', 'before_fallback_tagline_text', 99, 3 );
```

I'm working on a site that's using ACF and Elementor. I need to create a hook that will insert a second field in between the chosen ACF and the fallback. (Hopefully I’m using those terms correctly.) In other words, in Elementor, you can say

1. Display this ACF.
2. If it’s empty, display the designated fallback.

What I’d like the hook to do is change that to

1. Display this ACF.
2. If it’s empty, display field_xyz.
3. If that’s empty too, display the designated fallback.

The code works if 'field_xyz' is another ACF, but I can't find the right thing to enter to get it to use the post title.

I also need a version of the code for images. Here again, it works fine if both the first choice and second choice are ACF, so I just need the right thing to enter to use post thumbnail (aka featured image) as the second choice.

## Update

@bcworkz at the WP support forum suggested the use of `$fallback = get_the_title( $post_id );` which works great for the text side of things.

But I’m still not finding the right thing for the featured image. I tried
`$fallback = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'large');`
`$fallback = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'large');`
`$fallback = the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'large');`
None of them work.

What I need is for the code to just insert the image. (Wish I could explain better.) I do know that if I create an ACF image field called `thumbnail_image` then use `$fallback = get_post_meta( $post_id,'thumbnail_image', true );` it works. But obviously that blunts the purpose of relying on the (already populated) featured image.